# Same window size on different monitors

Tags: x11, fonts, multi-monitor

I am using two screens, one is 1920x1080 and the other one is 1280x1024. They have different dpi values, so the second screen is higher than the first one, although having a lower resolution.

Is there some way to stop windows and text being bigger on the second screen?

Comment: Set the same dpi on both screens?